# Adding log data into DynamoDB item (a la MongoDB)? Or in a related table?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a scenario where (for example), I have records in a database that represent files stored on a server. And every time a user (logged in or anonymous) visits that file, their geodata gets logged. Currently, with MongoDB, I just store all the geodata on the file document itself so I can do one read and have access to it all.

If I were to migrate to DynamoDB, what would be the best and most cost-efficient way of building this schema? My thought is that with enough visitors and hence geodata, the item size could grow to a point where it requires more RCUs to fetch a particular file record, even if I don't care at that moment about the log history. Does it make more sense to build a separate table for geodata log, and reference it as needed, a la RDBMS style?